# Display multiple values without comma

Tags: php, mysql

How do I display my `Tags` values as post tags like this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/kpo4r9cr/)?

**PRODUCT TABLE**

```
+----+--------+--------------------------+
| ID |  Name  |           Tags           |
+----+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | Shirt  | Shirt,Clothes,Blue-Shirt |
|  2 | Shoes  | Shoes,Red-Shoes          |
|  3 | Jacket | Jacket,Clothes           |
+----+--------+--------------------------+
```

**CODE**

```
<?php
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") or die (mysql_error());
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{ 
?>
    <div class="post">
        Product name : <?php echo $rows['name']; ?>
        <ul class="tags">
           <li>Tagged :</li>
           <li><a href="#"><?php echo $rows['tags']; ?></a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

My code has given this [result](https://jsfiddle.net/qar8Lrc6/).

Comment: You could use `explode();` to create a array of each item's tags and then loop them.

Comment: I don't know how to use `explode();`, Could you please give me for some example?

Comment: [I'll simply use `implode` and `explode`](https://3v4l.org/sG9fm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="post">
    Product name : <?php echo $rows['name']; ?>
    <ul class="tags">
        <li>Tagged :</li>
       <?php $tg = explode(",", $rows['tags']);
        foreach($tg as $t){
          echo '<li><a href="#">'.$t.'</a></li>';
        } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
<?php
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") or die (mysql_error());
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{ 
?>
    <div class="post">
        Product name : <?php echo $rows['name']; ?>
       <?php  $tags = explode(",", $rows['tags']);?>
        <ul class="tags">
           <li>Tagged :</li>
           <?php foreach($tags as $tag) :?>
           <li><a href="#"><?php echo $tag ?></a></li>
          <?php endforeach;?>
       </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Please see documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()` like that:

```
<?php
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") or die (mysql_error());
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{ 
    $tags = explode(",",$rows['tags']);
?>
    <div class="post">
        Product name : <?php echo $rows['name']; ?>
        <ul class="tags">
           <li>Tagged :</li>
           <?
           foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
           ?>
              <li><a href="#"><?php echo $value; ?></a></li>
           <?
           }
           ?>
       </ul>
    </div>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

**Explanation:**

I have explode `$rows['tags']` with commas and making an array of tags and than use `foreach` loop for print each tags inside the separate `<li>`

Comment: An explode remove commas between text?

Comment: @VintageBeef: u can say that, but its exploded the string with , defiantly it removes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use loop simply use `implode` and `explode` function like as

```
echo "<li><a href='#'>".implode("</a></li><li><a href='#'>",explode(",",$rows['tags']))."</a></li>";
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/sG9fm)

Answer (score 0):

Just kindly use this elements
..`<table>`
..`<td></td>`
..`<th></th>`
..`<li></li>`
..`</table>`
try all of this